# Snowpark Python: Create a new column with list of values

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Suppose I have input data as

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

I want to add Column C with some list of values like: [1,3,5,7]
**Expected output:**

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 |

```
result = [1,3,5,7]
df = df.with_column("new_column",  result)
df.show()
```

I have tried this approach to add column in existing DF with new column

Comment: It doesn't work like that, the column has to be computed by using a specified expression `col` which still points to columns from original DataFrame not a variable or another DataFrame. See the examples from [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.with_column.html#snowflake-snowpark-dataframe-with-column)

Comment: This is just a workaround. You can create a new dataframe:
  `result = [1,3,5,7] `df_res = session.create_dataframe(result).to_df('newCol')
    
and then do a join/merge with existing dataframe. Make sure to have some column between two dataframes.